# Incorrect float asignment

Tags: c++

I have the following class

```
class Viewport
{
public:
    Viewport();
    ~Viewport();

    void setSize(float x, float y);

private:
    float  _X;
    float  _Y;
};

void Viewport::setSize(float x, float y)
{
    //Conditionals used to make sure that the viewport stays inside the [0.0f, 1.0f] range

    if(x < 0.0f)
        _X = 0.0f;
    else if(x > 1.0f)
        _X = 1.0f;
    else
        _X = x;

    if(y < 0.0f)
        _Y = 0.0f;
    else if(y > 1.0f)
        _Y = 1.0f;
    else
        _Y = y;

}
```

And I create vector of Viewports

```
Viewport vps[3];

uint _NumCascades = 3;

for(uint i = 0; i < _NumCascades; i++)
    vps[i].setSize(i * (1.0f/_NumCascades), 0.0f);
```

The weird error occurs when `i == 1` and `i==2` at line `_X = x;` because `_X` is assigned the value `1051372203` instead of `0.33333334f`

Comment: Works fine in my machine, and it looks like too serious a blunder to be just an obscure bug in some specific compiler version. Is this code exactly the one causing this strange behaviour or just a simplified version?

Comment: Setting _X and _Y should work. Using operator-= for the width and height is strange, however.

Comment: Is this all of your code? You don't have a `main` function, and `uint` isn't a type as far as I know. Can you post a complete compilable example that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Given that all your attributes, and especially `_X` and `_Y`, are reserved for the compiler it's not improbable that the compiler is using `_X` for something else and getting your code confused. Please just don't ever use leading underscores in your names.

Comment: @Gorpik yes this is a simplified version of my code because my program is too complex, I also tried to compile this simplified version and it works correctly... I'll try to narrow the code that produces the error.

Comment: @MarkB Changing the names fixed it! Make that an actual answer to I can  accept it.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Although I entirely agree this is invalid code, I'm interested in exactly what caused this to break.

Comment: @J99 I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate C++ Compiler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All of  your attributes, and especially _X and _Y, are reserved for the compiler and it's not improbable that the compiler is using _X (since it's so short) for something else and getting your code confused.

The C++ language reserves a subset of names that start with underscores for the implementation. In this case, underscore and a leading capital are reserved in all scopes/cases. The rules aren't terribly complicated but to prevent accidentally using a reserved name it's simplest to avoid leading underscores on identifiers entirely.

Answer (score 5):

The bit pattern of 1051372203, `0x3eaaaaab` is the bit pattern of the `float` value `1.0f/3` in IEEE754 format. So the assignment works, and at some place, the bit pattern is interpreted as an integer. For `i == 0`, the bit pattern of the `int` (or `unsigned int`) 0 and the `float` 0 are identical.

Where that happens can't be inferred from the posted code.

Answer (score -1):

For each Viewport inside the array you have to call the constructor (create the objects):

```
for(uint i = 0; i < _NumCascades; i++)
{
    vps[i] = ViewPort();
}
```

You also need to implement the constructors and assign all attributes inside your class a value, e.g. `0`. Before dividing `1.0f/_NumCascades` you should cast your `_NumCascades` to `float` using `static_cast<>()` to prevent `C++` from inline casting:

```
vps[i].setSize(static_cast<float>(i) * (1.0f/static_cast<float>(_NumCascades)), 0.0f, 1.0f/static_cast<float>(_NumCascades), 1.0f);
```

Right now, you have an array of pointers, which point possibly at a random place in memory, therefore the random value.